# Una vista dos modelos

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, bootstrap-5

tengo 2 modelos en MVC , estaciones & modelos

```
public partial class Modelo

        {
            public Modelo()
            {
                Scraps = new HashSet<Scrap>();
            }
    
            public int Idmodelo { get; set; }
            public string? Modelo1 { get; set; }
    
            public virtual ICollection<Scrap> Scraps { get; set; }
        }
    public partial class Estacion
        {
            public Estacion()
            {
                PartEstacions = new HashSet<PartEstacion>();
                Scraps = new HashSet<Scrap>();
            }
    
            public int Idestacion { get; set; }
            public string Estacion1 { get; set; } = null!;
            public int Orden { get; set; }
    
            public virtual ICollection<PartEstacion> PartEstacions { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Scrap> Scraps { get; set; }
        }
```

Un controlador

```
public class ScrapController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ScrapSystemContext _context;


        public ScrapController(ScrapSystemContext context)
        {
            _context= context;
        }
        public async Task <IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Modelos.ToListAsync()); //Correcto
        }

    }
```

Y una vista, en la que estoy usando Bootstrap, como ven en el controlador pude mandar los valores del modelo(mvc) **Modelo**, pero no logro hacer que se envíe los datos del modelo **Estaciones**, trate de implementar la propiedad ViewBag, pero en la vista no se como importar los datos de **Estaciones** sin usar **@model**, que si uso 2 en la vista, lo marca como erróneo, dejo el código de mi vista y una imagen de como tengo que implementarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vista:

```
    @model List<ScrapSystem.Models.Modelo>
    
    <h1 style="color: #ff8000;">Captura</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <select class="custom-select">
                        <option selected>Modelo</option>
                        @foreach(var modelo in Model)
                        {
                            <option value=@Html.DisplayFor(m=> 
    modelo.Idmodelo)>@Html.DisplayFor(m=> modelo.Modelo1)</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <select class="custom-select">
                        <option selected>Correciones y anomalias</option>
                        <option value="1">One</option>
                        <option value="2">Two</option>
                        <option value="3">Three</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="background: 
 #ff8000;">
                        Enviar
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Utiliza un ViewModel. Te sugiero https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY para que veas los fundamentos de ASP Net MVC 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regrese con la solución a mi problema, cree un nuevo modelo, un controlador y una nueva vista, llamados **Captura** en donde contenía los atributos que necesitaba de los modelos **Modelo** & **Estación** además agregue los de un tercer modelo que vi que también ocuparía para la vista en un futuro, dejo el modelo a continuación:

```
public partial class Captura

{
    public Captura()
    {

    }
    public int Idestacion { get; set; }
    public string Estacion1 { get; set; } = null!;
    public int Orden { get; set; }
    public int Idmodelo { get; set; }
    public string? Modelo1 { get; set; }
    public int Idcorrecion { get; set; }
    public string Correccion1 { get; set; } = null!;
    public int Idarea { get; set; }
}
```

Después construí el controlador, use las propiedades ViewBag, use la variable _context, que es el contexto de la conexión a mi DB:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Modelos = _context.Modelos.ToList();
            ViewBag.Estaciones = _context.Estacions.ToList();
            ViewBag.Correcciones = _context.Correccions.ToList();
            return View();
        }
```

Y en la vista, cree 3 variables en el constructor, cree un objeto de tipo lista de los modelos a los que hago referencia, y después hago un casteo con el ViewBag como el que hice en el controlador:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    var modeloslist = (List<Modelo>)ViewBag.Modelos;
    var estacioneslist = (List<Estacion>)ViewBag.Estaciones;
    var correcioneslist = (List<Correccion>)ViewBag.Correcciones;
}
```

Para hacer la llamada de la lista en el formulario, lo hice con la sentencia Html.Displayfor y el uso de un foreach:

```
    <select class="custom-select">
                        <option selected></option>
                       @foreach(var item in modeloslist)
                        {
                             <option value=@Html.DisplayFor(x=> 
item.Idmodelo)>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Modelo1)</option>
                        }
                    </select>
```

Agrego una imagen ilustrativa, además que dejo los enlaces a referencias que use:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

https://www.mejorcodigo.com/p/65952.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843657/pass-model-to-view-using-viewbag

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465376/when-should-i-use-html-displayfor-in-mvc

Answer (score 0):

creo "ViewData" es lo que buscas. En tu controlador puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
       public ActionResult VerDetalles(int id)
        {
            //Logica de consultas 
            ViewData["MiTabla1"] = miTabla1;
            ViewData["MiTabla2"] = miTabla2;
            return View();
        }
```

Y en tu vista basta con lo siguiente:

```
var miTabla1 = ViewData["ComoLaNombreasteEnELControlador"] as MiTabla1;
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="MiCampo" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="XXX" value="@miTabla1.MiCAmpo">
```

Saludos